# Данные с 1С в html

Tags: html, 1с

Попробую вкратце описать мою ситуацию. 
Я пишу сайт для сотрудников компании. На нем имеются все возможные материалы, которые будут покупаться сотрудниками(понимаю всю хрень данный работы, но начальство так решило)
Есть 3 планшета на каждом из которых есть датчик считывания электронных ключей на подобие :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сотрудник , при поднесении своего ключа к этому датчику, имеет право купить все что ему нужно. на ключиках имеется баланс. Фирма сама ежемесячно закидывает баланс, для личных нужд сотрудников.  На каждого сотрудника есть свой ID. НО есть такое условие что на сайте, при поднесении ключа, должно отображаться имя и фотография этого сотрудника! Сайт связан с базой 1С. Я знаю как при поднесении ключа выводить имя этого сотрудника, однако с его фотографией, проблемка. Есть у кого какие идеи?

Comment: Оффтопик: сотрудники сами покупают материалы для работы?!

Comment: Забыл упомянуть, на ключиках еще имеется баланс. На этот баланс можно купить что угодно, в пределах фирмы. Фирма сама ежемесячно закидывает баланс, для личных нужд сотрудников. Короче все тут так за мудрено, но надо чтобы было.

Comment: @Ifrat все дополнения к вопросу, следует писать не в комментариях, а в самом вопросе

Answer (score 1):

Не понятно в чём проблема.
Идей множество есть: 
Можно выцеплять фото из SQL базы напрямую. 
Можно получать средствами COM.
Можно написать REST сервис на стороне 1С который делает всё что хочешь. 
Это что сходу придумалось.

Answer (score 1):

В три этапа:
1. Создаем папку \Фото_Сотрудников\ кладем туда картинки ...
2. В 1С прописываем для каждого сотрудника имя-файла картинки
3. При получении данных из 1С получаем также имя-файла картинки из нашей папки